# IPV6 ServerSocket is still listening even after application crash

Tags: java, sockets, ipv6, serversocket, netstat

I created a ServerSocket using:

```
InetSocketAddress inetsktaddr = new InetSocketAddress(0);
ServerSocket sckt = new ServerSocket();
sckt.bind(inetsktaddr);
Socket socket = sckt.accept();
```

when the application is running, using netstat i found,

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:49906          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9196
TCP    [::]:49906             [::]:0                 LISTENING       9196
```

SOMETIMES WHEN THE APPLICATION CRASHES, netstat result says:

```
TCP    [::]:49906             [::]:0                 LISTENING       9196
```

when searched for the process id 9196, no such process exists. It was the java.exe process id when the application was running. What is the reason for this to happen?

**I am using java 1.5 and Windows 7 Professional**

**EDIT**

After sometime i found the following:
my application starts mysql database. Sometimes when java.exe crashes, mysql will not crash. The db server will be up only. When this issue came (:: alone in listening state), i killed mysql process, immediately that :: socket stopped listening. So mysql is somehow preventing the :: to go away when java crashes. Not able to find reason for it.

Comment: a similar problem is found here. You might get some idea with it. http://superuser.com/questions/215351/how-do-i-kill-a-process-that-is-dead-but-listening

Comment: Java 1.5? That is many years out of date. Try using a current supported Java version.

Comment: The reason for it is that the child process inherited the socket.

Comment: Hi @EJP, the child process (mysql) will not inherit ipv4? ipv6 server socket is only listening. Any reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i found the reason, its a JVM Bug. (http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6598160)

Child processes will inherit ONLY IPV6 SOCKET HANDLES AND NOT IPV4 SOCKET HANDLES. Hence the issue came to me.

Fix is i should either upgrade JVM or listen only in ipv4 server socket.